# how to import packages in omnetpp?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I downloaded the INET library from the following link : https://inet.omnetpp.org/Download.html
and now I am trying to use INET modules in my project. I imported the INET project and then i am importing the packages but they are giving me errors. Can you tell me why?
I tried these :
      import inet.networklayer.autorouting.ipv4.FlatNetworkConfigurator;
      import inet.nodes.inet.Router;
      import inet.nodes.inet.StandardHost;

I also tried this instead   import inet.src.inet.node.inet.StandardHost;

Comment: Whats the exact error message? Some lines of code and more context would be also nice.

Comment: You will not get any meaningful answers until you provide correct description of your problem. Your question currently could be summarized like this: You are using INET & you have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information to answer this with certainty, but my guess is that your own modules are in a separate project. In this case you have to reference the INET project from your own project (Right click on your project/ Properties / Project references / click the INET project)